# Computing $\int_{(0,\infty)^{r-1}}\frac{x_1^{\gamma_1}\cdots x_{r-1}^{\gamma_{r-1}}}{\left(1+x_1+\cdots+x_{r-1}\right)^{\gamma_1+\cdots+\gamma_r+r}}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> Prove that
> $$\int_{(0,+\infty)^{r-1}}
>   \frac{x_1^{\gamma_1}\cdots x_{r-1}^{\gamma_{r-1}}}{
>    \left(1+x_1+\cdots+ x_{r-1}\right)^{\gamma_1+\cdots+\gamma_r+r}}
>    \,dx_1\cdots dx_{r-1}
>   =\frac{\gamma_1!\cdots \gamma_r!}{\left(r+\gamma_1+\cdots+\gamma_r-1\right)!}.$$

**My attempt**

Denote the integration by $I$.
Note that
$$
a^{-m}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(m)}\int_0^{+\infty} t^{m-1} e^{-at}\,dt.
$$
It follows that
\begin{align*}
&\qquad I\cdot (\gamma_1+\cdots+\gamma_r+r-1)!\\
&= \int_{(0,+\infty)^{r-1}}\int_0^{+\infty}
  {x_1^{\gamma_1}\cdots x_{r-1}^{\gamma_{r-1}}}\,\,  
        t^{\gamma_1+\cdots+\gamma_r+r-1}
        e^{-(1+x_1+\cdots+ x_{r-1}\,\,)t}
        \,dtdx_1\cdots dx_{r-1}\\
&= \int_0^{+\infty}\int_{(0,+\infty)^{r-1}}
  {x_1^{\gamma_1}\cdots x_{r-1}^{\gamma_{r-1}}}\,\,
        t^{\gamma_1+\cdots+\gamma_r+r-1}
        e^{-(1+x_1+\cdots+ x_{r-1}\,\,)t}
        \,dx_1\cdots dx_{r-1}dt\\
&= \int_0^{+\infty}
  \gamma_1!\cdots\gamma_{r-1}! 
        t^{-(\gamma_1+1)-\cdots-(\gamma_{r-1}\,\,+1)} 
        t^{\gamma_1+\cdots+\gamma_r+r-1}
        e^{-t}dt\\
&= \gamma_1!\cdots\gamma_{r-1}! \int_0^{+\infty}
        t^{\gamma_r}
        e^{-t}dt\\
&= \gamma_1!\cdots\gamma_{r}!.
\end{align*}
We are done.

**I want to know more approaches to this problem since this method is not the usual way to compute integration for me. Any ideas would be highly appreciated!**

Comment: This is related to the *generalized* beta function. A nice treatment of this and integrals of the sort go that in your OP can be found in ***Jones, F. Lebegue integration on Euclidean space.  Jones & Bartlett Learning; Revised edition (November 22, 2000)*** The computation are beautiful, but long so if you can take a look at the book it will be much better for you than any MSE posting.